# Доступ к файлу из Background / BeginConnect

Tags: c#, wpf

Открываю лог-файл в главном потоке. Запускаю Connection в асинхронном режиме, `BeginConnect` / `EndConnect`, из этих функции пытаюсь записать в лог файл результат операции. Но вылетает исключение "Поток не может получить доступ к файлу, так как владельцем является другой поток". `Dispatcher` не доступен, `lock` не помогает. Что можно сделать?

Comment: Какой лог-файл? Какой Connection[?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XAP0Mu2Qos)

Comment: Просто текстовый файл, который открываю на запись в функции MyConnectCallBack() и в который я хочу записать текст.